Как организовать хранение электронных документов для веб-приложения?
Я врач-кибернетик, разрабатываю веб-приложение для медицинского документооборота. Как лучше организовать хранение сканов медицинской документации (объем ~ 1Тб)? Сейчас схема выглядит так: есть веб-приложение (сайт на арендуемом хостинге); в больнице стоит сервер с Apache, выпллняющий роль файлового хранилища (+ там крутятся несколько python скриптов); на сайта с сервера через http подгружаются фото сканов.
Есть ли пути улучшения этой схемы? Не хочется использовать целый сервер просто в качестве файлового хранилища. Имеет ли смысл для этой цели установить NAS (либо сделать на коленке бюджетный NAS из роутера и внешнего жесткого диска)? Будет ли выигрыш в быстродействии в таком случае?


Если использовать NAS, то плюсами будут производительность, достаточно удобное управление(за счет встроенных функций, например, копирования) и масштабируемость(как знаю, можно легко увеличивать объем хранилища).
В случае с "бюджетным" NAS можно реализовать это с помощью FreeNAS, только там вроде довольно муторно происходит настройка и поддержка, а производительность будет уже варьироваться в зависимости от того, какой роутер или жесткий диск возьмете.

В общем, NAS как раз и будет балансом между производительностью и бюджетом
А если говорить про улучшения, то в голову сразу приходит облачное хранилище, там и физ.оборудование не беспокоит и провайдеры предлагают высокую доступность и резервное копирование, да и легко масштабировать его.
Можно еще и оптимизировать кэшированием или использовать CDN. Была бы информация про то, как у Вас реализована файловая структура, то может и там чего добавил.
